# download file (vcf) from webview ios swift

Tags: php, ios, swift, webview

I'm making a new start in learning `iOS-programming`.
My first attempt is an app (simple webView) for downloading vcf-files (for saving in iOS contacts). It works on desktop (html/php) but the same web code stop in `webView`.

There are some examples here but they doesn't seem to be for swift3.
Here is the start. On that page i have an url for redirect to somepage.php and there I set the headings via php to act as a file for download (vcf).
But... errors

Hope someone has the time to point me in the right direction

```
let url = NSURL (string: "https://someplace.com/contacts/");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL);
    web.loadRequest(requestObj as URLRequest);
```

Comment: `But... errors` Which error you are getting?

Comment: Also in swift 3 instead of converting `NSURL` to `URL` and `NSURLRequest` to `URLRequest ` use directly.

`let url = URL (string: "https://someplace.com/contacts/")
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url:url!)
    web.loadRequest(requestObj)`

Comment: Cant get the log in here with correct format, its a mess. But one line:
    nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_error [8.1 999.999.999.999:443 cancelled socket-flow (null)] Socket protocol sent error: [32] Broken pipe

Comment: Even if i point my nsurl directly to a .vcf file on the server it doesnt do anything. If I browse to the file with safari in ios it handles it correctly and asks if I want to save the contact? I guess that webview doesnt contain all of Safaris api, or maybe it is invoking another api from safari wich I dont embed... just guessing.

Comment: you can load request and open website / url in webview. but in my opinion IOS won't let you download something from there. because you are in different app at that time. So, for different app container would be different. That's the matter. It's near to impossible

Comment: There is examples from 5 years ago with almost identical problems that were solved. But that was with old Objective-C and ios 7-8. More recent solutions is also available but they were too extensive and addressed other things as well. But they could... so I believe it is possible.